# Defining a relationship between one User and other model fields in django

Tags: python, django

I've been working on a testProject and it's such that a User can have multiple projects and those projects can have many contractors. Contractors have to first register themselves and they are available to be work on different projects.The problem is, after defining a user and adding multiple projects along with many contractors, if i try to login by registering another User, then same projects appear for the second user as well, even without creating any new projects..how can i separate a particular user's data from another User's?

Here are my models:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):    ## the client is the user
     user=models.OneToOneField(User)
     def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Contractor(models.Model):
   name=models.CharField(max_length=128)
   url=models.URLField()
   bill_rate=models.IntegerField(default=0)
   slug=models.SlugField(unique=True)

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
      self.slug=slugify(self.name)
      super(Contractor, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
   def __unicode__(self):
      return self.name

  class Project(models.Model):
    contractor=models.ManyToManyField(Contractor)
    client=models.OneToOneField(UserProfile, null=True)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=128)
    slug=models.SlugField(unique=True)
    contractor_hours=models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       self.slug=slugify(self.title)
       super(Project, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __unicode__(self):
       return self.title
```

and these are my views for registering a new User, Contractor,and the dashboard view:

```
def user_login(request):
   context_dict={}
   if request.method=="POST":
      username=request.POST.get('username')
      password=request.POST.get('password')

      user=authenticate(username=username, password=password)

      if user:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/keeper/dashboard")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Your account is disabled")
      else:
        print("Invalid login details: {0}, {1}".format(username, password))
        return HttpResponse("Invalid Login details supplied")
   else:
       return render(request, 'keeper/index.html', {})


 def addContractor(request):
     context_dict={}
     registered=False
     if request.method=="POST":
         contractor_form=ContractorForm(data=request.POST)

         if contractor_form.is_valid():
             contractor=contractor_form.save()
             registered=True
         else:
             print contractor_form.errors
     else:
         contractor_form=ContractorForm()

     return render(request, 'keeper/addContractor.html', {'contractor_form':contractor_form, 'registered':registered})

  def dashboard(request):
      context_dict={}
      project_list=Project.objects.filter(client__user=request.user).order_by('-title')
      contractor_list=Contractor.objects.order_by('-name')
      context_dict['Projects']=project_list
      context_dict['Contractors']=contractor_list
     return render(request, 'keeper/dashboard.html', context_dict)

   def addProject(request):
     context_dict={}

     if request.user.is_authenticated():
     current_user=request.user.username
     context_dict['user_name']=current_user
     #print current_user
     contractor_list=Contractor.objects.all()
     context_dict['contractor_list']=contractor_list

     if request.method=="POST":
        form=ProjectForm(request.POST)
        project_title=request.POST.get('title')
        contractor_value=request.POST.get('contractor_selected')
        contractor=Contractor.objects.get(name=contractor_value)
        #print project_title, contractor
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            get_recent_project=Project.objects.get(title=project_title)
            #print get_recent_project
            get_recent_project=Project.objects.get(title=project_title)
            ##print get_recent_project
            get_recent_project.client=current_user
            get_recent_project.save()
            get_recent_project.contractor.add(contractor)
            #print get_recent_project.contractor.all()
            #print get_clientOfProject
            return success(request)
           else:
            print form.errors
        else:
          form=ProjectForm()
          context_dict['form']=form
    else:
      print "none"
   return render(request, 'keeper/addProject.html', context_dict)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You always display the full project list, completely ignoring the contractor:

```
  project_list=Project.objects.order_by('-title')
```

Try to filter the projects by those owned by the currently logged in user:

```
  project_list = Project.objects.filter(
      client__user=self.request.user
  ).order_by('-title')
```

Note that you also always show every contractor not only those associated with a project.

Comment: Hey, i tried to go with your solution but it didn't work. so i traced out the problem and lead me to my Project model wherein i have used client attribute set to the UserProfile as foreignKey field..i tried changing it to OneToOneField but still didn't work..then i made some changes in my add project view and find out the it is required to pass a User class instance to the Project Client field.so, when i try to get a project_list for the current client  i get none..can u help me with that?